# "functions of {intensity/the intensity/intensities} with respect to wavelengths" Which option is correct?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural

What is the correct option from the three below, please? Is it better to use plural or singular? Should be there the articles?

> ... are functions of **intensity (or flux)** with respect to wavelength.
> ... are functions of **the intensity (or the flux)** with respect to the wavelength.
> ... are functions of **intensities (or fluxes)** with respect to wavelengths.

Comment: Are they both (flux and intensity) the same?

Comment: Yes, I mean some plot, where intensity can be replaced by flux.

Comment: Any of those could be correct - it depends on the surrounding context and how you had already been talking about those variables.

Comment: It is the first sentence of the section. Profiles are functions ... Thus, the variables are not mentioned before.

Comment: That still doesn't help narrow things down - do these functions operate on flux/wavelength in general, or does each one operate on a specific flux/wavelength variable that is different for each "profile"? Really, it's impossible to answer a question like this based on a sentence fragment.

Comment: It is in general. It is a definition of the word profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grammatically say any of

Profiles are functions of intensity with respect to wavelength.

Profiles are functions of the intensity with respect to the wavelength.

Profiles are functions of intensities with respect to wavelengths.

The first would be closest to defining what profiles are. The second would be about multiple profiles that depend on the intensity and wavelength. The third would be stating that you have multiple situations with profiles defined for each.

These sentences are possible grammatically, but not mathematically. You cannot have a function of intensity with respect to wavelength. You can have a function of intensity, where intensity depends on wavelength. You can have a function of two variables - intensity and wavelength. Alternatively you can have a graph of intensity with respect to wavelength, or perhaps a derivative or an integral of intensity with respect to wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether to use an article "the", no article, or a plural, the best choice is the singular with no article. Since you've given a sentence fragment, it's hard to understand what is meant, but these would be possible expressions:
This is a plot of intensity as a function of wavelength.
or
This is a plot of intensity with respect to wavelength.